# "Guidelines" on whether a person who davens b'yechidus has to read eichah on Tisha B'av

Tags: tisha-bav

Can anyone who has access to the sefer "Guidelines" on the Three Weeks and Tisha b'Av by Rabbis Jaeger and Barclay tell me what if anything they say about a person who davens without a minyan reciting eichah on Tisha b'Av night?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what it says -

"**312. Should *Eicha* and *kinnos* be recited by a person who must remain at home?**

A person at home should try to recite them, if possible."

The source given in the back is

"מ''ב סק''ה, תשובות ונהגות הנ''ל"

I seem to remember a while ago that a friend of mine who is a Rabbi mentioned that Guidelines doesn't always present a whole picture based on the sources they give and often omits more lenient notes and views.  As always, CYLOR.

Comment: Great answer, @wizzardmr42. Just out of curiosity, though, would "lenient" in this context mean the onen wouldn't have to lein Eicha himself at home, or wouldn't be permitted to?

Comment: @JoshK Good question!  The same Rabbi friend says that there isn't really any true leniency or stringency anyway as any chumrah (stringency) in one thing inevitably causes a kullah (leniency) somewhere else.  I'd guess that people would view "lenient" as not having to recite Eicha and kinnos at home and that's the kind of thing that might not make it in from the sources from some opinions, but I'm speaking as a somewhat cynical layman - not from any position of halachic authority